# Setting zoom without select in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, zooming, active-window

Is it possible to set up zoom level based on screen resolution without `Select`?

I have followed the code:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1:AC1").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19439177/1903793

Desired code would be something like:

```
Range("A1:AC1").Width.Zoom=True
```

**Update. Why do I want to avoid Select?**

1. My sheet has hidden columns based on user settings. So some columns of the range A1:AC1 are hidden. I cannot select single column because this particular column may be hidden.
2. Selection triggers events. Of course I can disable the events but disabling the events has some side effects which I want to avoid.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414426/excel-2007-vba-zooming-without-using-select

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is what I have ended up with. Solution is resistant to hidden columns. I do not select columns but shape. Add a rectangle, name it "BoxForZoom". It should be wide just enough for your zoom. Then apply the following code:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("BoxForZoom").Visible = True
Sheet1.Shapes("BoxForZoom").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Sheet1.Shapes("BoxForZoom").Visible = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Just measure the current window width and the range's width.  Then you can use those values to set a scaling ratio. Note - this needs some additional validation and error handling, but it should give the basic idea.

```
Private Sub ZoomToRange(target As Range)
    'Get the window from the target range.
    Dim wnd As Window
    Set wnd = ActiveWindow

    'Find out what you need to scale to.
    Dim scaling As Long
    scaling = 100 * wnd.Width / target.Width
    'Limit to max and min zoom level.

    If scaling > 400 Then
        wnd.Zoom = 400
    ElseIf scaling < 10 Then
        wnd.Zoom = 10
    Else
        wnd.Zoom = scaling
    End If
    'Scroll to the upper left cell
    target.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not pass the test when some columns are hidden. Is it possible to get a true range width without unhiding hidden columns?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin - You can, but you'll need to calculate it manually by looping over the columns.  If they aren't hidden (i.e. `rng.Columns(1).Hidden`), add the width.

Comment: Some columns in the range may be hidden, depending on user choice. I am looking for solution without unhidding any of them.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin - You don't *have* to hide them. `If rng.Columns(x).Hidden = False Then width = width + rng.Columns(x).Width`

Answer (score 2):

This works, but will not make you happy.

Since we want column **AC** *(which is column 29)* to be visible, we start with `Zoom` = 100 and reduce it one step at a time until there are 29+1 columns in the `VisibleRange`:

```
Sub ShrinkWindow()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range

    For i = 100 To 1 Step -1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = i
        Set r = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
        If r.Columns.Count = 29 + 1 Then Exit Sub
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Zooming can be done easily by creating a larger image of the selected cells (like 1.5 times) or by increasing the font size :

[image]

[image]

Review this samples : [Zoom the selected cells](https://eksi30.com/zoom-the-selected-range/)